# Crack the code: Roman numerals. There is a picture of a statue with a discus and a picture of the colosseum

Tags: cipher

There is a picture of a statue with a discus and a picture of the colosseum.

CD XXV CLXIX CCLI CDXLI CCCLXI CCCLXI I CXLIV CDXLI CD XXV CLXIX

What is the coded message?

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure I have the right answer yet, but shouldn't the fourth group of letters have a `V` in it somewhere? (Slightly revised answer below)

> if you change the fourth group to `CCLVI, then the code consists of a series of perfect squares in Roman numerals:
>  <s>400 25 169 256 441 361 361 144 441 400 25 169</s> (missed one!)
>  400 25 169 256 441 361 361 1 144 441 400 25 169

If so, then

> Calculating the square roots and converting the results to letters (A=1, B=2, etc.) gives us:
>  `T E M P U S S A L U T E M`
>  And according to Google Translate, "tempus salutem" means "Time saving" (?)
>  (Is that the answer?)

Comment: +1 just for the answer itself. I think it might be right :P

Comment: @mdc32 Oops, missed a bit. I've updated the answer, but I'm still not sure if it's right.

Comment: +1 Just add that the message is a blatant historical hoax: the alphabet of the ancient Romans lacked the letters *J*, *U* and *W* (in fact *U* was written as *V*).

Comment: I'm no Latin guru, but TEMPUS could be related to temple and SALUTEM to salute, preserve.  So it could be "the temple salutes you", "the temple guards you" or some other variation.  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tempus#Latin http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salutem#Latin http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saluto#Latin